# hosintg WCF rest services in .net webforms app

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, rest

I have a traditional .net web application with .aspx pages and code behind files...

I want to use some jquery on the UI and wanted to ass json services to connect things like grids from jquery-easyui. I have seen some bad options like using .aspx pages to return json content type and standalone wcf samples but I want to host the services in IIS because the application is on a hosted online provider.

what is the simplest method that would be good practice to use for this and how do I implement it in VS2012 and my local IIS hosted site plus th production internet site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Web.Api to create rest services and host them as part of your website.
Have a look here for a complete tutorial : http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api.

Comment: I am not using MVC, so I think this is out.

Comment: You can turn your web app into a mvc super easily. I did it to use web.API for a huge web app (1640 man-days of work) a few moth ago. Did it in less than a day: I created a new project with mvc, copied all the code from the original web app like it was before (same folder, every etc.), ignored the routes that ends with '.aspx' and voila, I could use web API.

Answer (score 0):

You can also include WCF services directly into your web application and configure them so they will return and receive JSON.
They look like this :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class YourServiceDoesJSON
{        
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public ReturnTypeThatWillBeTransformedIntoJSON GetWhatever(string parameterIfYouNeed)
    {
        // do something
        return new ReturnTypeThatWillBeTransformedIntoJSON();
    }

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public SomethingElse PostWhatever()
    {
            ...
    }
}
```

The config file for this service looks like this :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebApp.Folder.YourServiceDoesJSONAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehaviors" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="WebApp.Folder.YourServiceDoesJSON" behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehaviors">

        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebApp.Folder.YourServiceDoesJSONAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApp.Folder.YourServiceDoesJSON" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

Note: this is how I did before I knew it was so easy to turn a web application into MVC; see my previous answer ;)